# grab more results from DB as the user scrolls down the page...what's that called?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to implement something like Facebook's news feed, where when you load the page 'x' number of results are shown. As the user scrolls down, more results are brought back from the database. What is that called? ....are there any good tutorials out there on it? I'd prefer something in jquery but am open to other suggestions (I am using html, php, jquery, mysql)

Comment: Lazy Loading and infinite scroll are two terms to look for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its called 'infinite scroll'

here's a jquery library to do that
http://www.infinite-scroll.com/